# BundleTable.EnableOptimizations is thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, global-asax

I added a logic to my app in order to enable debugging production.
I pass `debug=true` to the querystring, I set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations to false` (and avoid optimize my js files) in **`Application_BeginRequest()`**.

My Q is **it thread safe**?
I try to run some tests by locking the code and it seems like it is thread safe (even though `BundleTable` is `static`) but I still have some concerned.

Thanks in advance,
Lior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most of .NET framework, the answer is

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

(from MSDN)

Since `BundleTable` is a static class, this means that all the properties are thread-safe.

That said, `BundleCollection` itself is not thread-safe - this shouldn't be a problem as long as you're not trying to use it in multiple threads for the same request (which is a bad idea for many reasons anyway).